# Live float from serverside into javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, live

I'm currently stuck in a project.

I have this javascript graph, which updates the data every second. Thing is, I would that data to be the latest variable from my serverside, or the latest rows in a database.

My current code looks like this.

```
events: {
    load: function () {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second

        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function () {

            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = <%= serverVar%>
            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Or at least, the relevant part. This is where the graph updates every second. But even though y is set to a serverside variable, it does not get the latest?

What have I done wrong?

The serverside language is ASP.net (C#)

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the server side variable in client. These server side variable are use only when html is generated before sending the response to client. You need to send ajax call to get the value from server side.

This is very good [article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) to understand how you would send call to server side to fetch data. I think you will need to send sync call instead of async so that you do not need to wait for response in call back function. You can send sync call by setting async:false in [jQuery ajax function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    data: "a=" + id,
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

The server side variable gets rendered only once during the initial page load. Then every time your code executes at the interval it will find the same value and hence you are seeing the updates.

To fix this in the setInterval you make an ajax call and fetch the latest value there. Once you have latest value you can add it to the graphy using your logic.

Comment: How would you suggest to do that? :)